# How to make the h1 tags appear in one(same) line using jsp

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have two text boxes one for first text and the other for second text. Each have a drop down
box for choosing the size(so they can be of different or same size). Right now I am able to choose different
sizes and it works fine. The trouble I am having is they are displayed in two different
lines like:

```
       first text
       second text
```

but I want them to be displayed next to each other. For example

```
      first text second text
```

The code that I have right now is as follows:

```
 <c:choose>
   <c:when test="${! (empty (properties['first']) && empty (properties['second']))}">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${properties['type'] == 'styled'}">
            <h1 class="aaaa">
                <span>first text</span>
            </h1>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <h2 class="bbb">
                <span class="putColor">first text</span>
            </h2>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${properties['type1'] == 'styled'}">
            <h1 class="aaaa">
                <span class="putColor">second text</span>
            </h1>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <h2 class="bbb">
                <span class="putColor">second text</span>
            </h2>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>       
    <div class="hhhh">

    </div>      
</c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

Comment: The question in the title contradicts with what you're really asking :) As to the concrete problem, multiple h1 tags next each other is semantically wrong. You should ultimately have only one with both texts. However the code is not self-documenting enough to understand why exactly this approach is chosen en what exactly the functional requirements are, therefore it's hard to give an answer how to use only one h1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `style="display: inline;"` to your h1 tags.  (Of course, really you should do this in your CSS file, but this will quickly tell you if it works.)